# How can I get the item ID in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a method that pulls a url name(varchar), a urlID(int) and its Enabled status(bit) from a database and populates the results to a CheckedListBox on a foreach loop. The problem I have is the checkedboxlist only seems to take a name and its checked status. What i need to be able to do is when a user has finished with there selections on a button event it reads CheckedListBox and gets the URL ID, and enabled status so I can then write this back to the database.

This is the code I am using:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create url names in check box list.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rows"></param>
private void CreateURLCheckBoxes(DataRowCollection rows)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            //Gets the url name and path when the status is enabled. The status of Enabled / Disabled is setup in the users option page
            string URLName = row["URLName"].ToString();
            int URLID = Convert.ToInt32(row["URLID"]);
            bool enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Enabled"]);

            //Adds the returned to rows to the check box list
            CBLUrls.Items.Add(URLName, enabled);

        }
        i++;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error
        Functionality func = new Functionality();
        func.LogError(ex);

        //Error message the user will see
        string FriendlyError = "There has been populating checkboxes with the urls ";
        Classes.ShowMessageBox.MsgBox(FriendlyError, "There has been an Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1: Create a class to hold the Name and Id with  a ToString() override that returns the Name

```
public class UrlInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
    public bool Enabled;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add instances of this class to your CheckedListBox

```
 UrlInfo u1 = new UrlInfo { Name = "test 1", Id = 1, Enabled = false };
 UrlInfo u2 = new UrlInfo { Name = "test 2", Id = 2, Enabled = true };
 UrlInfo u3 = new UrlInfo { Name = "test 3", Id = 3, Enabled = false };

 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(u1, u1.Enabled);
 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(u2, u2.Enabled);
 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(u3, u3.Enabled);
```

Step 3: Cast SelectedItem to UrlInfo and retrieve the .Id

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    UrlInfo urlInfo = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index] as UrlInfo;
    if (null != urlInfo)
    {
        urlInfo.Enabled = e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked;
        Console.WriteLine("The item's ID is " + urlInfo.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above is meant to demonstrate the concept and isn't necessarily perfectly implemented. You might want to have properties instead of fields for Name and Id, initialize them via the constructor and provide no setter for immutability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better create a simple class containing a `string` (your url) and an `int` (the id), override the `ToString()` method to return the url, and add those objects to the `Items` property of the `CheckedListBox`.
When you get the selected object, you just have to cast it into your new class, and you can access both properties.

Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string  ToString()
    {
         return this.Url;
    }
}
```

And then when you add the objects :

```
CBLUrls.Items.Add(new MyClass { Id = URLID, Url = URLName }, enabled);
```

Answer (score 0):

This control has a Value Member and a Display member. I think you can do what you need if you use the Name as the display member and the ID as the value member.

Comment: There isnt a display member or value member that i can see under a checkboxlist control Mickey.